# if active = true than paint it red in javascript

Tags: javascript

i need to check if active = true than paint the text red, but i can not do it.

```js
var products = [
 {name: 'Коля', active: true},
 {name: 'Вася', active: true},
 {name: 'Петя', active: false},
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++ ){
    
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML =  products[i].name + " " + products[i].active;
    if( products[i].active == true ){
     products[i].name.style.color = "red";
    } 
    ul.appendChild(li);
    document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

Comment: Here you go! Six fellas who have the exact same answer :D You just had a minor flaw, the rest of your code totally works!

Comment: @Nebulosar  hahaha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `li` instead of `products element`

```
li.style.color = "red";
```

```js
var products = [{
    name: 'Коля',
    active: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Вася',
    active: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Петя',
    active: false
  },
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = products[i].name + " " + products[i].active;
  if (products[i].active == true) {
    //products[i].name.style.color = "red";
    li.style.color = "red";
  }
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set created `li` element's `style` property instead of `products[i].name`

```
li.style.color = "red";
```

instead of

```
products[i].name.style.color = "red";
```

```js
var products = [
 {name: 'Коля', active: true},
 {name: 'Вася', active: true},
 {name: 'Петя', active: false},
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++ ){
    
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML =  products[i].name + " " + products[i].active;
    if( products[i].active == true ){
     li.style.color = "red";
    } 
    ul.appendChild(li);
    document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `products[i].name.style.color = "red";` with `li.style.color = "red";`

```js
var products = [{
    name: 'Коля',
    active: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Вася',
    active: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Петя',
    active: false
  },
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = products[i].name + " " + products[i].active;
  if (products[i].active == true) {
    li.style.color = "red";
  }
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

An alternative is to use class instead on inline styles

```js
var products = [{
    name: 'Коля',
    active: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Вася',
    active: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Петя',
    active: false
  },
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = products[i].name + " " + products[i].active;
  if (products[i].active === true) {
    li.classList.add("red");
  }
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to style `li`, instead of the data and append only one `ul` at the end.

```js
var products = [
        { name: 'Коля', active: true },
        { name: 'Вася', active: true },
        { name: 'Петя', active: false },
    ],
    ul = document.createElement("ul"),
    li, i;

for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML =  products[i].name + " " + products[i].active;
    if( products[i].active) {   // no need for checking a boolean for true
        li.style.color = "red"; // add to element
    } 
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

document.body.appendChild(ul); // only once
```

Answer (score 1):

`products[i].name` is not an HTML element. So you can not set `style` on that. To set `style` on `li` change :

```
products[i].name.style.color = "red";
```

To

```
li.style.color = "red";
```

**Please Note:** `if(products[i].active == true)` is equivalent to `if(products[i].active)`. You do not need to compare a boolean value with `true` or `false` explicitly:

```js
var products = [
  {name: 'Коля', active: true},
  {name: 'Вася', active: true},
  {name: 'Петя', active: false},
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++ ){ 
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML =  products[i].name + " " + products[i].active;
  if( products[i].active ){
    li.style.color = "red";
  } 
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is style.color in your case? 
My guess is you want to paint the DOM node completely red. 
Try using the `li` element instead of the product object

```js
var products = [
 {name: 'Коля', active: true},
 {name: 'Вася', active: true},
 {name: 'Петя', active: false},
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++ ){
    
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML =  products[i].name + " " + products[i].active;
    if( products[i].active == true ){
     li.style.color = "red";
    } 
    ul.appendChild(li);
    document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```